# How to remove PartialFunction input bound

Tags: scala

Is there any way to convert `PartialFunction[Int,_]` to `PartialFunction[Any,_]` ?

Following code throws `ClassCastException`

```
val f: PartialFunction[Int, _] = ...
f.asInstanceOf[PartialFunction[Any,Any]].isDefinedAt("a")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your partial function in a new `PartialFunction`, as has already been suggested:

```
val g: PartialFunction[Any, Any] = { 
    case x: Int if f isDefinedAt x => f(x)
}
```

Another option is to extend `PartialFunction` and manually override `apply` and `isDefined`.  You can even do this with an anonymous class.  For example:

```
new PartialFunction[Any, Any] {
    def apply(x: Any) = f(x.asInstanceOf[Int])
    def isDefinedAt(x: Any) = x.isInstanceOf[Int] && f.isDefinedAt(x.asInstanceOf[Int])
}
```

You might also play with `Function.unlift` and `PartialFunction.lift`, or `PartialFunction.condOpt`:

```
import Function._
val g = unlift[Any, Any] { 
    case x: Int => f.lift(x)
    case _ => None 
}

//Alternative with condOpt
import PartialFunction._
val g = unlift(condOpt(_ : Any) { case x: Int => f.lift(x) }.flatten)
```

If this is common enough, you might even enrich `PartialFunction` with the desired method:

```
implicit class RichPartialFunction(val pf: PartialFunction[Int, Any]) extends AnyVal {
    implicit def withAnyDomain = new PartialFunction[Any, Any] {
        def apply(x: Any) = pf(x.asInstanceOf[Int])
        def isDefinedAt(x: Any) = x.isInstanceOf[Int] && pf.isDefinedAt(x.asInstanceOf[Int])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Wrap it in a new partial function which is undefined for inputs that aren't of type `Int`:

```
val g: PartialFunction[Any, Any] = { case x: Int if f isDefinedAt x => f(x) }
```

Comment: It is proper solution, but with this we loose all info about defined cases.

Comment: Thanks, but it now throws class cast exception. I`ve ended up with own PartialFunction implementation.